# variance of the number of fixed points for a permutation group

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability, permutation-groups, random-permutations

It is reasonably well-known that the variance of the number of fixed points for $S_n$ equals $1.$ Now, what about other transitive permutation groups on $\{1, \dotsc, n\}?$ Presumably much is known. I am particularly curious about which groups have the highest variance...

Comment: If I understand properly what you are asking, for the subgroup of $S_n$ generated by an $n$-cycle, the mean number of fixed points is $1$, and the variance is $n-1$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $\pi(g)$ be the number of fixed points of a permutation $g$ on $\Omega=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and $G$ be a transitive permutation group on $\Omega$. Then, by the orbit counting formula (usually attributed to Burnside, but previously known by Cauchy and Frobenius too), the variance $V(\pi)=E(\pi^2)-E(\pi)^2=E(\pi^2)-1=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\pi(g)^2-1$ is $r-1$, where $r$ is the number of orbits of $G$ on $\Omega\times\Omega$. Note that $r$ is also the number of orbits of a point stabilizer $G_1$ on $\Omega$. In particular, $V(\pi)\le n-1$, with equality if and only if $|G|=|\Omega|=n$.

Comment: Well, that trumps my comment.

Comment: Truly, you are wise in the ways of science :)

Comment: r is usually called the rank of the permutation group.